# How to compare arrays without using .equals and with a false boolean

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, compare

I am having to compare arrays without using the .equals method and currently the program runs correctly except when I have two variables such as

```
int[] y = {8,8,8};
int[] z = {8,8,9};
```

My program says this is true when it should say it is false. The following is my CompareArrays code:

```
if (arrayOne.length == arrayTwo.length) {
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
      if (arrayOne[i] == arrayTwo[i]) {
         return true;
      }
   }
}

return areEqual;
```

I have to use the `boolean areEqual = false` and return it at the end.

Comment: Hello Andrew, this is very simple, whenever you are checking, the first iteration you are already returning true, you are not waiting for the second iteration

Comment: how can I correct that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of immediately returning when they are equal, check for inequalities and if there's one, then `return false`. If the `for` loop finishes without returning, then you can safely `return true`.

```
if (arrayOne.length == arrayTwo.length) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i ++) {

        if (arrayOne [ i ] != arrayTwo [ i ] ) {

            return false; 
        }

    }

    return true;

}
return false;
```

Comment: @AndrewDeWitt ["I have to have boolean areEqual = false. I cannot change it "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782661/how-to-compare-arrays-without-using-equals-and-with-a-false-boolean#comment92487090_52782716).

Comment: I believe that requirement was added later after the question was created, sorry I missed it

Comment: @Mayhem [nope, it was in the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/a1df649e-1622-4adf-94e2-096f5eff4cd9/view-source).

Comment: it still worked I just said return areEqual; instead of return false at the end like you did @Mayhem

Comment: Anyhow, @AndyTurner is actually correct, I just want to shout out to that

Answer (score 0):

You are returning true as soon as you find a matching pair of elements, and never updating `areEqual`. You need to keep going until you find a pair of elements which *aren't* equal, or reach the end of the array.

Instead, use the `areEqual` variable to tell you if you have found something - anything - which makes them unequal. Once you have found something to make them unequal, you don't need to check any more:

```
boolean areEqual = false;  // Redundant assignment; but meh, if you've got to use this...
areEqual = arrayOne.length == arrayTwo.length;
for (int i = 0; areEqual && i < arrayOne.length; ++i) {
  areEqual = arrayOne[i] == arrayTwo[i];
}
return areEqual;
```

Comment: Anybody care to share what they don't like about this approach?

Comment: I have to have boolean areEqual  = false.  I cannot change it

Comment: @AndrewDeWitt there you go.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast#comment435922_17204?

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for your help.  this way works as well. I'm not sure who didn't like it.  I just saw mayhems first

Answer (score 0):

@Mayhem 's answer is correct. I just want you to show you a more cleaner way (by removing the `if` nesting):

```
if (arrayOne.length != arrayTwo.length) {
  return false;
}

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i ++) {
  if (arrayOne [ i ] != arrayTwo [ i ] ) {
    return false; 
  }
}
return true;
```

Comment: (`!==` isn't a Java operator)

Comment: edited, thought i filtered the questions by javascript ;)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. You avoid the nesting of ifs, which can often be tricky.